# Send and receive Objects via Server/Client connection in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, object, server, client

I am working on a project in Android Studio.
The plan is to send Objects via local Server in Java (Eclipse) to a mobile app, programmed in Android Studio. Here is the code from the Server:

```
public Server() {
    ServerSocket server = null;

    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(1010);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    try {
        while (true) {
            Socket s = server.accept();
            System.out.println("new client");
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject(new Packet("Hi"));
            System.out.println("Objekt versendet");
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here from the client:

```
public Client() {
    Socket s = null;

    try {
        s = new Socket("localhost", 1010);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        Object o;
        o = ois.readObject();
        Packet p = (Packet) o;

        System.out.println("[Von Server]: " + p.getS());
        s.close();
    } catch ( IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When a new client has connected to the server it should send a packet to the client, including a String called "hi".
When I start the server and client in Eclipse it works fine.
When I start the client in Android Studio (VD), this error turns up although the Class Packet is existing:

```
ava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Packet
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2258)
W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1641)
W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:657)
W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1782)
W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
```

Comment: `Send and receive Objects via Server/Client connection in Android Studio`. Wrong description. There are no connections running in Android Studio. Please adapt.

Comment: `When I start the client in Android Studio, `? Do you mean 'when i start the client on my Android device' ?